# sushi rice or paste

Tags: sushi, sticky-rice

I do what the instructions say...I rinse my sushi rice till the water is clear, I soak the rice for 30 minutes, I bring the rice and water to a boil, cook on low for 20 minutes and what I get could be used as wall paper paste. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you edit the question to include how much water you use for the quantity of rice? And do you discard the soaking water or use that to cook it?

Comment: It sounds like you might've cooked it in too much water.  What proportions did you use?